# Есть ли смысл ставить CDN в данном случае?

Tags: cdn

есть сайт, клиенты - только Россия. Есть смысл ставить CDN?

Answer (score 1):

Смысл есть всегда, если используемый ресурс запрашивается достаточно часто.
Конечно, зависит и от других факторов - например, если сравнительные скорости выдачи с сайта и CDN в пользу сайта - но в целом, при прочем равном, качественная CDN предпочтительней всегда.

Плюсы и как по экономии ресурсов сервера, по скорости работы сайта, по скорости доставки, дополнительной унификации разработки/использования.